# How to enhance a standard Transaction, to add a Parameter ID to one of the field in one screen?

Tags: parameters, transactions, abap, autofill, sap-erp

Transaction MB1A

That is the field I am interested in.
[image]

When I analyze the field, it has no Parameter ID

[image]

However I'd like to be able to call this transaction and for that field to be automatically set.
I have done this in the past like this:

```
set parameter id 'WRK' field mv_werks.
      call transaction 'MB1A'.
```

But there is no parameter ID in this case.
So can I set a Parameter ID, or is there any workaround?
Could I perhaps call the transaction in another way than with `call transaction` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put an enhancement in subroutine

`transaktions_init`

of include

```
MM07MFT0_TRANSAKTIONS_INIT
```

You can pull in the parameter ID you want and populate the field:

```
RM07M-WERKS
```

You could use either an implicit enhancement or there are several explicit enhancement points in that subroutine.

Comment: actually, that's exactly what i eventually did :P

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [the documentation of `CALL TRANSACTION … USING …`](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_70/en/ABAPCALL_TRANSACTION.htm) - there's a complete code sample in there.

Comment: when i tried that, it gave me an error message (i don't remember the speciffic error and i can't check just yet). it said that another transaction was openned in batch processing mode, and i had to wait for it to finnish, so i took another approach. As far as I can tell `CALL TRANSACTION ... USING` only opens transactions in batch processing mode. Thx for the input though, it seems I can't use it though.

Comment: What was the exact coding you used, and what exactly was the error message?